# MySQL Error 1292 on insert text

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1292

I am trying to insert a combination of 2 fields into one field and every time I do this I get an error about truncating data.

The code:

```
insert into sharppatentdb.Inventor (InventorFull)
select InventorFirst + " " + InventorLast 
from sharppatentdb.inventorsource;
```

The error:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '`Rossi-Wolter`'

All source fields are `VARCHAR(64)` The InventorFull field is `VARCHAR(511)` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that `InventorFull` needs to be `511` characters based on this statement:

> All fields are VARCHAR(255)

because somewhere in the mix the concatenation of the two fields `InventorFirst`, the single space, and `InventorLast` is greater than 255 characters. When you build fields for concatenated values they need to be the combined size of both fields as well as any additional characters.

To more clearly depict the reason that your `InventorFull` field needs to be `511` characters - your two fields are `255` characters ***and*** you're adding a single character in between:

```
255 + 255 + 1 = 511
```

further, as shown in the comments, it's worth noting that this will not work on MySQL versions that are ***less than*** 5.0.3.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I'm guessing you're looking for `255 + 255 + 1`?

Comment: Very good. I assume this works in MySQL versions `<` MySQL 5.0.3?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, are you saying that versions less than 5.0.3 wouldn't support a field of `511` characters? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: That's correct. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) (I just think it's worth noting in your answer)

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh that makes sense, I thought that it just allowed up to 255 chars.  I didnt realize it filled with space.  I will just make my source fields 127 chars then.  Thanks!